# Plot data for many days in bar chart without date information

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset containing:

- days of the week
- counts for each day of the week

For example, my dataset may be:

```
{ 
  "days": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"],
  "counts": [10, 5, 3, 8, 6, 2, 9, 7, 10, 8]
}
```

I want to plot the data on a chart using `matplotlib`. However, when I try to do so, `matplotlib` automatically collapses the data points according to the categories on the x axis instead of showing the data sequentially. For example, this is the graph I get:

[image]

Evidently, the graph has been "collapsed" by the repeating categorical labels on the x axis. How can I prevent this from happening, and show everything on the graph without using any date information? I would like to maintain the x axis labels as "Mon", "Tue" etc. as well.

My current code for the graph is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = { 
  "days": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"],
  "counts": [10, 5, 3, 8, 6, 2, 9, 7, 10, 8]
}

plt.bar(data['days'], data['counts'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set as x-range the indices to your lists. And then set the days as xticklabels. Additionally, you could color the bars using the day to show the repeating structure:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
  "days": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"],
  "counts": [10, 5, 3, 8, 6, 2, 9, 7, 10, 8]
}
x = range(len(data['days']))
cmap = plt.cm.plasma
colors = [cmap((xi % 7) / 10 ) for xi in x]
plt.bar(x, data['counts'], color=colors)
plt.xticks(x, data['days'])
plt.show()
```

PS: Optionally you could hide the tick marks with `plt.tick_params(axis='x', length=0)`.
[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you give data['days'] as the *x* coordinate of each bar so they stack up. In order to avoid this, you need to separate the *x* coordinates from the *x tick labels*. Here is one way to do so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = { 
  "days": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"],
  "counts": [10, 5, 3, 8, 6, 2, 9, 7, 10, 8]
}
plt.bar(x=np.arange(len(data['days'])), height=list(data['counts']),tick_label=list(data['days']))
plt.show()
```